# Cross-Platform Password Management

Tags: software-recommendation, password

I am looking for a password manager that is compatible with open-source password database files, such as those used by KeePass (.kdb) or PasswordSafe (.psafe3). Both of those projects have terrible Mac clients - I'm looking for something a little more polished, but can still share password databases with Windows and Linux users.

Answer (score 5):

The excellent [1Password](http://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/import_passwords.html) by AgileBits supports import for both of the formats you mention:

> ### 1Password can import data from many popular applications, including:
>
> AppShelf
>   AutoID
>   Data Guardian1 (formerly Password Retriever)
>   eWallet2
>   KeePass and KeePassX
>   LicenseKeeper
>   Minefield
>   Password Safe 3
>   PasswordWallet by S3
>   Passwords Plus3
>   RoboForm Passcards and Safenotes
>   SplashID by SplashData
>   TurboPasswords (formerly Cloak)
>   Web Confidential

Highly recommended app, well worth the purchase price.  (EDIT) 1Password does not include Linux support at present, just OS X, Windows, iOS and Android.

Comment: There is not 1Pwd for Linux though.

Comment: No Linux support is the only major flaw with 1Password.  However, you can use the 1PasswordAnywhere feature.  For security reasons, I wouldn't use the recommended DropBox functionality, though.  That being said, putting it on a USB stick has its own issues.  Personally, when I'm away from my Mac, I just use the 1Password iPhone app (also for Android).

Comment: edited the answer to mention lack of Linux support.  still a great app.

Comment: @Max, Richard, da4 - We're keeping track of departmental equipment logins, not personal logins, and we have engineers on all three platforms. We're trying to decide on a password file format to keep in our version control system. (We have a near zero budget for this, no fancy web applications, alack.) - most of the OSS password managers work spiffy on windows and Linux both - just not on the Mac.

Comment: I haven't used it in that kind of environment (or anywhere outside of home), but have you looked into https://www.gpgtools.org/ ?  Be sure to update this question if you ever do find a solution to your liking.

Comment: 1Password requires a plaintext export from inside KeePass - it cannot read or import a .kdb file.